# iOS enterprise apps and backup to new devices

Tags: ios, backup, enterprise, transfer

We've been developing a bunch of iPad apps for a client with the enterprise program. Now with the release of the new iPad there's been complaints the the already installed apps we developed are not getting transfered to the new devices ( when they do a restore from backup on the new pads ).

I haven't been able to find any information regarding this issue in the apple documents. My first thinking was that you are unable to restore apps developed on an enterprise program to "any device" ( that they needed to be installed manually ). But after we ran a test in house we noticed that it was pretty random. 2 out of 4 enterprise apps did not transfer to the new device.

Any insight into this issue will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Do the apps have different bundle identifiers? Maybe your enterprise certificate is not valid for all of the apps.